# Weather web API

Tags: web-services, backend, weather, weather-api

What is the best web API for getting weaher information for any city in the world?

I need the hourly weather forecast and time of sunlight information.

And I will request the information using the city name. For New York I will pass: New York - NY, USA. As I'm using in Google API: http://www.google.com/ig/api?hl=en&weather=New+York+-+NY,+USA

I'm developing a backend application.

Comment: "Best" by what criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've previously used [yahoo weather rss feed.](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/). It has sunsire, and sunset times, not too sure about the hourly forecast requirement you have..

Answer (score 1):

The National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration's National Weather Service has XML feeds at http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/.

Comment: How can I build the url for any city in the world?