# Web API's - How are they implemented?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api

Good Day

I know very little about Web API's and how they are actually implemented. I know most Apps that have API's available, document on how it is supported and implemented to integrate with the app.

Now my question: What are the different ways of implementing a Web API? Does it have to incorporated into a custom Web App(written with a programming language) or can it be done using HTML and Javascript?

I want to implement a Web API but I do not know where to start. It is written in XML and JSON. The purpose of me wanting to do this is just to learn more about API's...Obviously I can't write one if I do not know how to implement one?

Where do I start?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend that you start by learning to use them, creating them isn't hard but creating a good one is and by gaining experience by using them is the first step.

Might I suggest you get stuck in with a simple application and post your questions as you go, a simple API call for retrieving the weather from a website would be a good "Hello World" application.

Comment: thank you. cool idea. But how do I make the call - Where do I start? And I assume I would need to find a popular weather app with good API support? Any suggestion on what API I can use? Since it is a Web API, will it be an HTML call (get, set, post etc)?

Comment: You might want to check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389792/weather-web-api

Comment: You can use a number of languages to call a Web API you need to pick one that suits your needs and get stuck in. There's plenty of languages and frameworks out there but start simple and go from there.